# 19.10: Persistent, brief wifi drops, Realtek RTL8822BE, HP Envy x360

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

I'm using my internal network card, has worked with no issues for months. No other devices on the network are experiencing drops. I changed the Wifi channel and checked for driver updates (none), reinstalled the drivers just in case.

My network card: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac

I ran journalctl --follow and screenshot the output when a drop occurred:

[image: journalctl output]

I don't really know what it means though. This line caught my eye: WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 27181 at drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/phy.c:1590 rtw_get_tx_power_params+0x288/0x680 [rtw88]

And of course the text in red.

I looked up process 27181: 0.1  0.1  14104  8624 Ss   15:20   0:21 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant

Can anyone tell me what any of this means?

Answer (score 0):

The same issue I've gotten on Ubuntu 22.04.1 with kernel 5.19.0-35.
After updating the kernel to 5.19.17 the issue was gone.

I have used the "[mainline](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/08/mainline-install-latest-kernel-ubuntu-linux-mint/)" tool for kernel upgrade.